# How does a PTR record help receiving mail servers detect spam?

Tags: email-server, ptr-record

Specifically, if I create a mail server with IP 1.2.3.4 and hostname bademail.example.com, and make sure I have a PTR record from that IP to that hostname, what has that achieved?

In a real world scenario, I use Mailgun to send my emails (service isn't relevant here) which uses a shared IP for sending with a PTR that resolves to mail13.static.mailgun.info. What does a receiving mail server do with this information to flag spam? It can't be checking the domain portion of my email address, because it's obviously not @mail13.static.mailgun.info, which suggests it's using the hostname present in the received by portion of the headers. But since anybody can create a PTR record that matches the IP and hostname they are sending from, given my first primitive example, I fail to see how this helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … But since anybody can create a PTR …

Anybody can't. PTRs are part of reverse DNS zones, that have to be properly delegated, and they are — to ISPs<sup>1</sup> typically. Wide ranges of ISP's IP networks allocated to SOHO-connections have PTRs absent or set to names that would indicate they aren't supposed to be legit mail relays.

__

1. In case anyone's interested: there's a way of reverse zones sub-delegations, but it requires
   customization on ISP's side and setup DNS server(s) to be running with static IP of course, so it's too much of a hassle for typical SOHO. Instead it's easier to provide editing of reverse zone upon request or via WEB-interface (which might be not done).